# bar3 showing only top surface, when using log scale

Tags: matlab, plot

When running

```
hBar = bar3(rand(6,8));

%// set(gca,'Zscale','log')    % Problem when using log scale

for k = 1:length(hBar)
    zdata = hBar(k).ZData;
    hBar(k).CData = zdata;
    hBar(k).FaceColor = 'interp';
end
```

Things come out fine

[image]

But if I comment in the line, which sets the Z axis to log scale, the body of the bars vanish...

[image]

Why so?

Comment: Interesting problem, but I rather doubt that there is a simple and elegant solution. I don't even think it's a bug. It's just that bar plots are not supposed to have a logical scale, as they always start with **zero** (or offsets to zero), which is a not defined on a log-scale. It's funny that Matlab allows you to set a log-scale, but just top surfaces can be useful to someone. I found some workarounds on google/fileexchange, but haven't tried any, but maybe it's worth having a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work out of the box is, as thewaywewalk commented, that those bars go along the z-axis from 0 to the given value, and 0 on a log-scale is infinitely far down. `bar3` does not provide a way to specify a baseline value other than 0. However, it is possible to achieve this with a hack.

After plotting the data

```
hBar = bar3(rand(6,8));
```

we manipulate the underlying surface data returned in `hBar`:

```
baseline = 0.1;
for i = 1 : numel(hBar)
    z = get(hBar(i), 'ZData');
    z(z == 0) = baseline;
    set(hBar(i), 'ZData', z)
end
```

This code assumes that every exact 0 in the surface ZData refers to the bottom of a bar, and replaces the value by the `baseline` chosen in the first line. Now a log-scale

```
set(gca,'Zscale','log')
```

provides a useful display, e.g.:

[image]

Because some of the `rand`-values are below our chosen baseline of 0.1, some bars extend downwards, but of course this can be avoided by choosing data and baseline in a matching way.